# De Rahm Cohomology of Complex Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, grassmannian

Since the complex Grassmannian $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)\cong SU(n)/S(U(k)\times U(n-k))$ is connected and simply connected, the first two de Rahm cohomology groups are given by
$$
H^0(G_k(\mathbb{C}^n))\cong \mathbb{R} 
\hspace{10pt} \hbox{and} \hspace{10pt} 
H^1(G_k(\mathbb{C}^n))\cong 0 \, .
$$
Poincaré duality then gives $H^{2k(n-k)}(G_k(\mathbb{C}^n))$ and $H^{2k(n-k)-1}(G_k(\mathbb{C}^n))$.

Those are the only ones I would know how to find. Is there a general result for the other de Rahm cohomologies of complex Grassmannians?

Comment: That can be found in p.193 of the book "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by P. Griffiths and J. Harris. A cell decomposition is constructed explicitly and all cohomologies computed.

Comment: Or you can search the term Schubert calculus to find more references.

Comment: Great, thank you for the reference!

Comment: See also Hiller's book "The geometry of Coxeter groups".